# why does the hot water boiler used for heat, open up and release water then close back up?

Tags: furnace

hot water boiler, occasionally opens and closes releasing water to floor. just started doing this (cold weather) does the relief valve need replaced? or is this a common action?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The relief valve is working as it should,likely the expansion tank has gone bad. The expansion tank has a air filled ballon inside that expands and contracts with the different temperatures of the water. Without it the boiler will fill up to the proper pressure then when the water gets hot the water pressure increases and then makes the relief valve go off and then the hole cycle starts again.